# Free on-line course of Statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, online-resources

I am interested in learning Statistics, but I am unable to join any regular course. Please, advise me how can I do any course in Statistics online myself, and free if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: to what level and to what aim?

Comment: I am interested in learning for stock analysis and sales analysis...but i am open to others as well since i am not sure what all statiatics could cover..i am also planning to learn r programming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great book for learning statistics: Hogg & Craig - Introduction to mathematical statistics. You can probably find it online.

You didn't precise what exactly you would like to know from statistics, there are many courses on the internet that cover only some specific topic like time series or linear regression. I am not sure about the free courses but I've heard that courses on datacamp (there's some kind of monthly subscription I guess) are really useful.

Comment: I am interested in learning for stock analysis and sales analysis...but i am open to others as well since i am not sure what all statiatics could cover..i am also planning to learn r programming..

Comment: If you want to use R, then I heard really good opinions on the datacamp courses. I did only a few of them (mostly the free ones) and they seemed really nice. If you know some basics, you could try studying Time series. Here is a good book that covers theory: https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf2943/ts.pdf, here you can have some theory with a little bit R-code: https://otexts.org/fpp2/, and you can check those datacamp courses.